# How to change webroot and make ftproot invisible to browsers?

Tags: .htaccess, ftp, root

I am trying to protect the ftp root by pointing the webroot to a specific subfolder in my ftproot

```
-root (sub.mydomain.com)
    -index.html (for testing, this should not show)
    -conf
    -src
    -public
        -index.html (this should always show)
```

I tried it by placing a .htaccess file in the fptroot like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /public [L]
```

I have tried a couple different ones as well from googling, but I end up getting access to the root/index.html anyways.

This one below actually redirects as desired, but then the /public_html/ shows in the browser which is clearly not what I want.

```
RewriteEngine On
 RedirectMatch ^/$ /public/
```

This one below does the same thing

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.mydomain.com/public [R=301,L]
```

I want everything but the root/public to be completely invisible to the browsing people. Many webhosts have this setup done for you by default but I don't have that luxury in this project.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you, put it in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```